# What is the join result for an empty collection

Tags: guava

I'm wondering, how exactly will Joiner.join behave if it is given an empty collection:

```
Joiner.on(",").join(new ArrayList());
```

I wonder, what is the expected behavior here. Will it return an empty string or a null? Or it depends on the platform and implementation of the library?

Comment: You could also try it yourself...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, check source:

```
public String join(Iterable<? extends Entry<?, ?>> entries) {
  return join(entries.iterator());
}
```

Next:

```
public String join(Iterator<? extends Entry<?, ?>> entries) {
  return appendTo(new StringBuilder(), entries).toString();
}
```

And finally (skip one method):

```
public <A extends Appendable> A appendTo(A appendable, Iterator<? extends Entry<?, ?>> parts) throws IOException {
  checkNotNull(appendable);
  if (parts.hasNext()) {
    ...
  }
  return appendable;
}
```

If your collection is empty `appendTo()` will return empty `StringBuilder`. So, result is empty string.